# MySQL default time format UTC or GMT?

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, utc, convert-tz

Hi I'm so confused with this UTC and GMT

I'm inserting in MySQL table as ex column "event_date" like "2010-07-01 23:50:00" (datetime) my client asking an option in front end as GMT +1 GMT +2 GMT -1 GMT -2 ...etc if I select any option GMT +2 the event_date will filter/list according to the GMT +2.

I have no idea how to proceed and after googling I found this

```
CONVERT_TZ( `field_eventdate_value` , '+00:00', '+10:00' )
```

and whether it works well and my client gave me a sample URL to check like this

http://www.forexpros.com/economic-calendar/

I'm working with drupal nodes

Thanks in advance,

Gobi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) are an excellent read.

```
CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)
```

`CONVERT_TZ()` converts a datetime value `dt` from the time zone given by `from_tz` to the time zone given by `to_tz` and returns the resulting value. Time zones are specified as described in Section 9.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”. This function returns `NULL` if the arguments are invalid.

The current values of the global and client-specific time zones can be retrieved like this:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

The `timezone` values can be given in several formats, none of which are case sensitive:

- The value 'SYSTEM' indicates that the
  time zone should be the same as the
  system time zone.
- The value can be given as a string
  indicating an offset from UTC, such
  as '+10:00' or '-6:00'.
- The value can be given as a named
  time zone, such as 'Europe/Helsinki',
  'US/Eastern', or 'MET'. Named time
  zones can be used only if the time
  zone information tables in the mysql
  database have been created and
  populated.

**PS:** Read about [GMT vs UTC](http://geography.about.com/od/timeandtimezones/a/gmtutc.htm) on About.com. GMT is the solar time at Greenwich, London while UTC] is a time standard based on International Atomic Time (TAI) with leap seconds added at irregular intervals to compensate for the Earth's slowing rotation. Both are same if viewed as a time-zone.