# Select Now() as CurrentDateTime mysql time zone

Tags: mysql, date, select, time, gmt

How can I use the `SELECT Now() As CurrentDateTime` for GMT, as it displays the tome as GMT-5.

Basically, when the time is: `2011-11-19 09:46:37` in GMT, it displays it as: `` `2011-11-19 04:46:37 ``

How can I set this for GMT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is by setting the time zone for your session:

```
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
```

[MySQL "time zone support" documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html).

There's also CONVERT_TZ, which is explained here: [MySQL default time format UTC or GMT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466630/mysql-default-time-format-utc-or-gmt)

Comment: How can I use this with the Select Statement

Comment: You do this before the SELECT statement (this is a per-connection setting, so it stays active after the select).

You can use the CONVERT_TZ() function if you don't want to (re)set the connection's time zone all the time.